# Binding an angularjs custom class directive to a SVG element

Tags: css, angularjs, svg

I'm trying to bind an angularjs custom class directive to a SVG element. The following plunker illustrates the core of my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/J4YafmSk6t7DScMRda4I?p=preview

As the console log shows, the custom class directive is correctly bound to the div element (blue). But nothing happens when clicking the rect element (red), suggesting that no binding occured.

I guess this must be related to some SVG specifics - is there any known workaround for this problem? When searching, I found issues related to class interpolation for SVG elements, but this is not the issue here...

Thanks by advance for your keen help!

Comment: You should add the sample code from your plunker to your question. Stack Overflow prefers that resources that are important for a question or an answer is available without relying on any external resources.

Answer (score 0):

If declaring the directive as an attribute instead of a CSS class is a solution you can use then that works.

```
directive('class1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function() {
                console.log("clicked");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SGC1v3r2XhwlPYKgHf5A?p=preview)

I've always had problems with CSS and SVG, so it does not really surprise me that this is just another thing that acts a bit wonky.

Comment: I checked it as valid, even if I'm a bit frustrated of being forced to avoid the class attribute...

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I don't know exactly why it won't work or how to fix it. You could always leave it unchecked and see if someone else comes along and suggests a better solution. It's perfectly fine to not accept an answer.

Comment: That was a way of recognizing your yet valuable contribution, as I do not have a sufficient reputation score "plus" it ^^

Comment: Dont't worry, I don't care about my rep on this site :)